# не правильно отображается JPanel

Tags: java, swing

Не могу правильно отобразить панели. Мне необходимо добавить последовательно две или более панели, при помощи компоновщика BoxLayout(по вертикали) на главную панель, но получается так, что накладывается одна панель panelTwo на mainPanel, и при этом занимает все пространство, помогите найти и устранить причину, вот часть кода, где и происходит вся компоновка, прошу заметить, что settingField это так же JPanel

```
    settingField.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel mainData = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelOne = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelTwo = new JPanel();

    mainData.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainData, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    mainData.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    panelOne.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40,40));
    panelTwo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40,40));
    panelOne.setBackground(Color.white);
    panelTwo.setBackground(Color.white);
    mainData.add(panelOne, panelTwo);
    settingField.add(mainData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mainData.add(panelOne, panelTwo);
```

С чего вы взяли, что в качестве `constraints` вы можете использовать `panelTwo`? Используйте методы с 1 аргументом:

```
mainData.add(panelOne);
mainData.add(panelTwo);
```

Comment: да, я ранее уже исправил это у себя, но к сожалению без изменения, при чем все отлично работает с другими компоновщиками, а с Боксом нет

Comment: У меня работает. Сверху одна панель, снизу другая.

Comment: если есть возможность, гляньте проект - https://github.com/Zherikhov/TicTacToe
буду весьма благодарен, я не пойму тогда почему  меня не работает

Comment: а если нет, то ничего страшного) все равно спасибо)

Comment: Поменяйте цвет одной из панелей и вы увидите, что все норм. С чего вы взяли, что они накладываются?

Comment: он не выдавал нужных размеров, которые я принудительно присваивал, но потом вычитал, что Box, заполняет все пространство, решил я это своеобразным способом, в главной панели задал Border, сделал отступ на севере и юге, а в центральную закинул Box, кидаю туда две панели и тадам, они нужных мне размеров

Comment: позвольте вопрос, это игра крестики нолики, я дошел до момента где у меня происходит прорисовка, кликаю мышкой - появляется крестик, затем кликаю мышкой еще раз - нолик появляется, и крестик исчезает, не знаете почему так может быть?

Comment: Обновите git. Я вижу только прорисовку крестиков...

Comment: обновил, я так подозреваю, что это из-за BufferedImage

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84273/discussion-between---and-vlad-zherihov).